# Laravel admin image URL not included port and causing image not found in edit form

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload a new image to an identity model, it can show the preview. But when I edit it, the image url not included with port by env(APP_URL)
[laravel admin form edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIMN4.png)

I check in the directory and the image is actually there.
[image in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1pUH.png)

However, I can still access it on my homepage by this code:

```
<img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$identity->picture_path)}}" alt="">
```

and its returned this in the browser:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/uploads/images/5d263cb580b1d800119a5211bc759fde.jpg" alt="">
```

This is my config/filesystems.php
[config/filesystems.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paFkv.png)